# What is the best way to collapse the rows of a SELECT into a string?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a  SQL statement ( or procedure ) I want to collapse the rows of this table into a single comma delimited string.

```
simpleTable

id  value
--  ----- 
1    "a"
2    "b"
3    "c"
```

Collapse to:

```
"a, b, c"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can concatenate using an embedded 'set' statement in a query:

```
declare @combined varchar(2000)
select @combined = isnull(@combined + ', ','') + isnull(value,'')
from simpleTable

print @combined
```

(Note that the first isnull() initialises the string, and the second isnull() is especially important if there's any chance of nulls in the 'value' column, because otherwise a single null could wipe out the whole concatenation)

(edited code and explanation after comments)

**Edit (ten years later):**

SQL Server 2017 introduced the [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function which provides an official way of concatenating strings from different rows. Like other aggregation functions such as COUNT(), it can be used with GROUP BY.

So for the example above you could do:

```
select string_agg(value, ', ')
from simpleTable
```

If you had some other column and you wanted to concatenate for values of that column, you would add a 'group by' clause, e.g:

```
select someCategory, string_agg(value, ', ') as concatValues
from simpleTable
group by someCategory
```

Note string_agg will only work with SQL 2017 and above.

Comment: sweet! I didn't realize you could do that. I always thought set and select worked the same for assignment.

Comment: you might want to make it "+ ISNULL(value,'')" because "+ value" will null out any portion of the string build up before the row with the null value

Answer (score 5):

This will only work in MSSQL 2005+

```
select value + ',' from simpletable for xml path ('')
```

..one way to prevent the extra comma:

```
select case(row_number() over (order by id))
when 1 then value else ',' + value end
from simpletable
for xml path ('')
```

Comment: if only there was a slick way to remove that last comma :)

Comment: added a slick way to remove that last comma :)

Comment: nice! I always forget about the row_number()

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @EmployeeList varchar(100)

SELECT @EmployeeList = COALESCE(@EmployeeList + ', ', '') + 
   CAST(Emp_UniqueID AS varchar(5))
FROM SalesCallsEmployees
WHERE SalCal_UniqueID = 1

SELECT @EmployeeList
```

Results:

```
1, 2, 4
```

Answer (score 0):

This is based on @codeulike answer, but will prevent losing the portion of the string that gets concatenated before a null "value" is concatenated on.

```
declare @combined varchar(2000)
select @combined = isnull(@combined + ', ','') + ISNULL(value,'')
from simpleTable

print @combined
```