# How to collapse rows into a comma-delimited list in an SQL Query in MySql

Tags: mysql

It is relatively simple in T-SQL to concatenate related values into a comma delimited string in an SQL Query (see here:  [What is the best way to collapse the rows of a SELECT into a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822615/what-is-the-best-way-to-collapse-the-rows-of-a-select-into-a-string) and here:  [What is the best way to collapse the rows of a SELECT into a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822615/what-is-the-best-way-to-collapse-the-rows-of-a-select-into-a-string)).  The latter link describes exactly what I need to do, but I need to do it in MySql, and the query that works in T-SQL doesn't work in MySql.  Any MySql experts out there know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is called [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
select group_concat(your_id) from your_table
```

Comment: Just found this - but you win!  Thanks!