# How to join two tables of mysql and concatenate multiple rows into single cell?

Tags: php, mysqli

How to join two tables of sql and concatenate multiple rows into single cell?

The Query which i am using::

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID;
```

Output which i got::

### CustomerName          OrderId

John Doe                                     101

John Doe                                     102

John Doe                                     103

John Doe                                     104

Expected Output::

### CustomerName          OrderId

John Doe                            101,102,103,104

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to collapse rows into a comma-delimited list in an SQL Query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475804/how-to-collapse-rows-into-a-comma-delimited-list-in-an-sql-query-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group concat is the easiest way to achieve the output you require.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` and aggregate by customer to generate a CSV list of orders:

```
SELECT
    c.CustomerName,
    GROUP_CONCAT(o.OrderID) AS OrderIDs
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Orders o
    ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
GROUP BY
    c.CustomerId;
```

Note that it would be preferable to aggregate by customer ID, if possible, because perhaps two or more customers have the same name.

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Use `group_concat`

```
  SELECT Customers.CustomerName, group_concat(Orders.OrderID) as OrderID 
  FROM Customers LEFT JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
  group by Customers.CustomerName;
```