# What is the most efficient way to concatenate a string from all parent rows using T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table that has a self-referencing foreign key that represents its parent row.  To illustrate the problem in its simplest form we'll use this table:

```
CREATE TABLE Folder(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, --PK
    parent_id int NULL,        --FK
    folder_name varchar(255) NOT NULL)
```

I want to create a scalar-valued function that would return a concatenated string of the folder's name and all its parent folder names all the way to the root folder, which would be designated by a null parent_id value.

My current solution is a procedural approach which I assume is not ideal.  Here is what I'm doing:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetEntireLineage
    (@folderId INT)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @lineage VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @parentFolderId INT

    SELECT @lineage = folder_name, @parentFolderId = parent_id FROM Folder WHERE id = @folderId

WHILE NOT @parentFolderId IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @parentFolderId = (SELECT parent_id FROM Folder WHERE parent_id = @parentFolderId)
        SET @lineage = (SELECT @lineage + '-' + (SELECT folder_name FROM Folder WHERE parent_id = @parentFolderId))
    END
RETURN @lineage
END
```

Is there a more ideal way to do this?  I'm an experienced programmer but T-SQL not a familiar world to me and I know these problems generally require a different approach due to the nature of set based data.  Any help finding a solution or any other tips and tricks to deal with T-SQL would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To know for sure about performance you need to test. I have done some testing using your version (slightly modified) and a recursive CTE versions suggested by others.

I used your sample table with 2048 rows all in one single folder hierarchy so when passing 2048 as parameter to the function there are 2048 concatenations done.

**The loop version:**

```
create function GetEntireLineage1 (@id int)
returns varchar(max)
as
begin
  declare @ret varchar(max)

  select @ret = folder_name,
         @id = parent_id
  from Folder
  where id = @id

  while @@rowcount > 0
  begin
    select @ret = @ret + '-' + folder_name,
           @id = parent_id
    from Folder
    where id = @id
  end
  return @ret
end
```

Statistics:

```
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 125 ms,  elapsed time = 122 ms.
```

**The recursive CTE version:**

```
create function GetEntireLineage2(@id int)
returns varchar(max)
begin
  declare @ret varchar(max);

  with cte(id, name) as
  (
    select f.parent_id,
           cast(f.folder_name as varchar(max))
    from Folder as f
    where f.id = @id
    union all
    select f.parent_id,
           c.name + '-' + f.folder_name
    from Folder as f
      inner join cte as c
        on f.id = c.id
  )
  select @ret = name
  from cte
  where id is null
  option (maxrecursion 0)

  return @ret
end
```

Statistics:

```
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 187 ms,  elapsed time = 183 ms.
```

So between these two it is the loop version that is more efficient, at least on my test data. You need to test on your actual data to be sure.

**Edit**

**Recursive CTE with `for xml path('')` trick.**

```
create function [dbo].[GetEntireLineage4](@id int)
returns varchar(max)
begin
  declare @ret varchar(max) = '';

  with cte(id, lvl, name) as
  (
    select f.parent_id,
           1,
           f.folder_name
    from Folder as f
    where f.id = @id
    union all
    select f.parent_id,
           lvl + 1,
           f.folder_name
    from Folder as f
      inner join cte as c
        on f.id = c.id
  )
  select @ret = (select '-'+name
                 from cte
                 order by lvl
                 for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
  option (maxrecursion 0)

  return stuff(@ret, 1, 1, '')
end
```

Statistics:

```
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 31 ms,  elapsed time = 37 ms.
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for the effort you've put into this, I truly appreciate it.  This place is awesome.

Comment: So, I implemented this in my actual database and it seems that the string concatenation query (select @ret = @ret + '-' + name) isn't concatenating the name from all rows.  I queried all rows from the cte and all the rows were there as expected, just not concatenated as expected by the concatenation query.

Comment: Well, I've narrowed it down and I'm a bit confused.  I do "select * from cte order by lvl;" and it returns all expected rows ordered appropriately by level.  When I do the concatenation query "select @ret = @ret + '-' + name from cte order by lvl" it does not concatenate all rows, just the last row.  When I leave out the order by clause, it concatenates all the rows appropriately, I just can't be guaranteed they're in the correct order.

Comment: It appears aggregate string concatenation using a select with an order clause is a known issue.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982286/tsql-string-concat-with-select-and-order-by-does-not-work-with-function-in-order . Mikael, did it appear to work in your solution?

Comment: I'm glad you got some enjoyment out of it.  Again, your help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

use a [recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003895/recursive-query-using-cte-in-sql-server-2005) to traverse the parents and then [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822615/what-is-the-best-way-to-collapse-the-rows-of-a-select-into-a-string) for concatenating into a string.

Answer (score 4):

A hierarchyid is often overkill unless you have a really deep hierarchy or very large sets of data that can take advantage of the indexing.  This is as fast as you can get without changing your schema.

```
 with recursiveCTE (parent_id,concatenated_name) as (
    select parent_id,folder_name
    from folder
    union all
    select f.parent_id,r.concatenated_name +f.folder_name
    from folder f
    inner join recursiveCTE r on r.parent_id = f.id
    )
    select folder_name from recursiveCTE
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for you:

```
 with cte (Parent_id, Path) as 
    (
    select Parent_Id,Folder_Name
    from folder
    union all
    select f.Parent_Id,r.Path + '\' + f.Folder_Name
    from Folder as f
    inner join cte as c on c.Parent_Id = f.Id
    )
    select Folder_Name from cte
```